# Metal-Insulator from number of atoms in the basis

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, metals, insulators

I have an issue understanding what A&M means while saying this in chapter 12:

> It is a reassuring exercise to go through the periodic table looking up the crystal structure of all insulating solid elements. They will all be found to have either even valence or **a crystal structure that can be characterized as a lattice with a basis containing an even number of atoms** [...]

Although it is clear why an insulator should have an even number of valence electrons, I can't figure out how the number of atoms of the crystal basis influences the conductivity.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simply that usually each atom will have an integer number of valence electrons, so if there are an even number of atoms per unit cell, there will be an even number of valence electrons per unit cell. So if spin interactions are negligible and only act as a source of degeneracy, all orbitals will be filled and there will be a gap to the next excited state.

As an aside, this picture is pretty hand wavy and not completely true. Mott insulators for example are the most famous exception to the "even electrons for insulation" rule.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you.